# foreach element in single array in particular format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreach

I'm new to rubyonrails. I need to collect `foreach` element as below array format

```
[
  [lat1, long1],
  [lat2, long2],
  [lat3, long3],
  [lat4, long4]
]
```

my code is

```
@outlet.each do |outlets|
  lat = outlets.latitude
  long = outlets.longitude
end
```

i can collect `lat`,`long` every loop. How can i format those element in above format?

Comment: If these are ActiveRecord objects, you can use [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to just fetched the attributes from the database, e.g. `Outlets.where(...).pluck(:latitude, :longitude)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.map` method (the result is what you want):

```
@outlet.map do |outlets|
  [outlets.latitude, outlets.longitude]
end
```

Comment: could you please tell me, how can i render that array?

Comment: you can render the array as a json: `render :json => @outlet.to_json`

Comment: how do pass that format to a javascript, which is in view page?

Comment: @users4393829 `<%= raw the_result_above_returned.to_json %>` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `inject`:

```
@outlet.inject([]) { |sum, outlets| sum << [outlets.latitude, outlets.longitude] }
```